# Run parallel Python code on multiple AWS instances

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, cloud

I have a Python algorithm that can be parallelized fairly easily.

I don't have the resources locally to run the whole thing in an acceptable time frame.

For each work unit, I would like to be able to:

1. Launch an AWS instance (EC2?)
2. Send input data to the instance
3. Run the Python code with the data as input
4. Return the result and aggregate it when all instances are done

What is the best way to do this?

Is AWS Lambda used for this purpose? Can this be done only with Boto3?

I am completely lost here.

Thank you

Comment: Are the instances independent of each other? Meaning, does one instance have to wait for other instance to finish, or they all get different input data, and run fully separate?

Comment: This sounds a lot like what **Hadoop** does. You might want to investigate Amazon EMR. It has a steep learning curve, but it is designed to do exactly what you are seeking.

Comment: The instances are not path-dependant, the input data is all different. But there is a lot of input data (8 billion records in total, split in 1M rows chunks)

Answer (score 0):

A common architecture for running tasks in parallel is:

- Put inputs into an **Amazon SQS queue**
- Run **workers** on multiple Amazon EC2 instances that:

  - **Retrieve** a message from the SQS queue
  - **Process** the data
  - Write results to **Amazon S3**
  - **Delete** the message from the SQS queue (to signify that the job is complete)

You can then retrieve all the results from Amazon S3. Depending on their format, you could even use **Amazon Athena** to run SQL queries against all the output files simultaneously.

You could even run multiple workers on the same instance if each worker is single-threaded and there is spare CPU available.

Comment: Is this suitable for a high volume of data? I would have around 8 billion rows x 10 columns, split in 8000x1M rows chunks

Comment: The above approach can handle very high volumes of data, but you might want to start by running it in smaller chunks to confirm it is working correctly. If the individual jobs run relatively quickly, another approach would be to trigger **AWS Lambda functions** from the SQS queue, which avoids the need to run Amazon EC2 instances. By default, they run up to 1000 concurrent functions but this can be increased. If the data being passed to each worker is quite large, the input data could be stored in Amazon S3 and a reference to that data can then be passed to the worker.